# java - how do i save the classes created after JIT to a file on the disk

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, decompiler, java-bytecode-asm

Sometimes I am using frameworks that instrument my code (byte code inject).

I remember that there is a way to tell the JVM to save the class after the instrumentation  with the new byte codes (so I can view it with a decompiler).

How do I do it? (What are the parameters )

Thanks.

Comment: JIT translates the byte code to native code doesn't it? So basically you want the native assembly code it would emit?

Comment: I remember there is a way to save the pre-native. Just after the instrumtation. fixed the question.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the Java Agent API?

Comment: Please elaborate. will it write my classes?

Comment: Just look at the [Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). It allows registration of an arbitrary number of transformers which are called one after another. Since they all get the class file (result of the previous transformer) as byte array it’s easy to register a transformer after all others which stores the final array to disk.See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html#transform(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain,%20byte[])